# I have a client using Epicor 9. They are on Windows 11 and they get error Im02 ODBC Driver Manager Data Source Not found

Tags: odbc, report, epicor

The error is only happening when they run one specific report Production Planning tool. They are using driver OpenEdge 10.2A64. I am not sure where to go from here. It is working on his old machine running Windows 10 64 bit. His new machine is Windows 11. I am not sure if Windows 11 broke something with ODBC.

I have Uninstalled and reinstalled Epicor and Crystal Reports.